# Selection Sort method error, incompatible types

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

Here is my code so far. I am getting an incompatible type in the first for statement. 
Required: boolean
Found: int

Not quite sure what I need to do to fix this.

```
public void selectionSort(int[] list){
    //implement selection sort here.  
    for (int i = 0;list.length -1;i++){
        int smvi = i;
        for(int j = i+1;j<list.length;j++){
            if(list[j] < list[smvi]){
                smvi=j;}
            if(i!=smvi){
                int temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[smvi];
                list[smvi] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here: `list.length -1`

What I think you want is `i <= list.length - 1`

Comment: Wow thanks you are correct. I just wasn't thinking about what was actually supposed to be happening there and just copied from my notes. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

The Error clearly states that it requires boolean type but found int.

```
list.length -1;
```

will not return any boolean values, it simply returns a integer. You too know that for(;condition;) syntax. Every condition will decide only based on boolean values.

You should change it to

```
i < list.length -1;
```